# Pdoc adds class info to every enum variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, documentation, pdoc

I don't know what exactly is going on, I don't have that great of an understanding of `Pdoc` but I am using it to create documentation of my source code. It usually works pretty well but I recently stumbled into a problem when documenting classes inheriting from `enum.Enum`. The class documentation works just fine but every single class variable I add to the enum  contains th whole documentation under it.

Is there any way to remove these?

Comment: Please add a minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of [pdoc](https://pdoc.dev) renders Enums just fine. Here is an example: https://pdoc.dev/docs/demo_long.html#EnumDemo

Comment: Please add context to any links so your Answer is self contained, meaning the answer needs to be here in the Answer itself. See ["Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It would be preferable if you could answer the Question in your own words here and link only as a reference.